# Flask terminal command not found

Tags: flask, virtualenv, flask-migrate

I found [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227360/installed-flask-in-a-virtualenv-yet-command-not-found) explaining that Flask 0.10 does not have the `flask` command. How should I initialize the database for Flask-Migrate?

I discovered this issue when following the documentation for [Flask-Migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). After installing the package and adding the configuration, the `init db` would not run.

```
(env) $ flask init db
-bash: flask: command not found
```

Comment: What is your OS? Is it linux or OsX?

Comment: Updated the question. I'm on OS X

Comment: I guess because I'm working on a 3+ year old project. I've upgraded to 0.11.  `flask run` cannot locate the Flask app, even though running `ENV` shows `FLASK_APP=run.py`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. And true, thank you for your help with the initial problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to Flask 0.11, which provides the `flask` command.

If you can't upgrade, install and configure [Flask-CLI](http://flask-cli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which backports the command to 0.10.

```
from flask_migrate import migrate

migrate = Migrate(app, db)
```

```
FLASK_APP=my_app.py flask db init
```

If you can't upgrade and don't want to install Flask-CLI, install and configure [Flask-Script](http://flask-script.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which is a previous system for adding commands and is still [supported by Flask-Migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#using-flask-script).

```
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask_script import Manager

migrate = Migrate(app, db)

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

```
python manage.py db init
```