# No module named flask.__main__ with global interpreter (OK with virtualenv)

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

I know that using virtual environments is the best practice, but I just want to sort out the issue for myself. So here is the story.
I have a Flask app, have set up a virtual environment, and I'm running everything on Windows. Which works great!
However if I run the very same app with my global Python interpreter which is **the same as my virtual one** - i get this error:

```
D:\Development\stempal>python -m flask run
C:\Anaconda3\python.exe: No module named flask.__main__; 'flask' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

Note that the very same command runs perfectly in the virtual environment:

```
(venv) D:\Development\stempal>python -m flask run
 * Serving Flask app "flask_app"
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

What is the difference?

Comment: Don't you have a package called `flask` by any chance lying around in `D:\Development\stempal\python`? That could by why the weird error message. But you still probably have differences between your two virtualenvs. Compare the output of `pip freeze` inside and outside the virtualenv.

Comment: No, there was no `flask` package anywhere close. However your comment about differences helped me solve it! Turned out that outside my virtual environment Flask was out of date and the old version simply didn't have `flask` command. Many thanks, @jbacko

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @jbasko, I started comparing the package lists inside and outside the virtualenv. Turned out my `flask` package was out of date and as mentioned [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227360/installed-flask-in-a-virtualenv-yet-command-not-found) it didn't have the `flask` command.
Upgrading Flask solved the problem.