# run flask web server on raspberry pi

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi

I installed Flask on my raspberry pi 3, then created a script that looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
     return "Hello World!"
```

when I type in the terminal the following line:
    FLASK_APP=hello.py flask run
I get 
    bash: flask: command not found, python helloflask.py does not do anything either. When I run the script with the mention command and script I get this:

```
xxxMINGW64 ~/Desktop/codes_
$ FLASK_APP=firstflask.py flask run
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2017 10:30:17] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [07/Sep/2017 10:30:17] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Why can't I see this on my pi?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I solved by appending the following to the script:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug = True)
```

Can anyone tell me why not working without this on pi but work on windows?

Thanks

Comment: Can you specify which version of flask you are using. Looks like flask 0.11.0 onwards the flask command is enabled. Also check `which flask` and check if the command exists in raspberry pi3.

Comment: 0.10.1 is the version, can you tell me how to upgrade it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a version less than 0.11 then you should be upgrading the flask version.

You can do that by using the command
`pip install --upgrade Flask`

[Installed Flask in a virtualenv yet "command not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30227360/installed-flask-in-a-virtualenv-yet-command-not-found)

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks again! One last question: Do you know why I can't open this http://127.0.0.1:5000/ on my android tablet? Thank you

Comment: @johnnycigar you should not use `127.0.0.1:5000` instead you should use `<ipaddress_of_raspberrypi>:5000`

Comment: I typed in without quotation marks: "192.168.0.17:5000" but I get This site can’t be reached

192.168.0.17 refused to connect. What can be the problem?

Comment: Please check few things. Port `5000` is open and secondly should check if `80` which is the http port is also allowed. But this needs a real look at the system.

Comment: Can you read this or should I send it to you in a different way? Thanks 
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1777/python     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:55405         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1152/python3  

tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -